# How can one join and leave Blockchain network?

Tags: blockchain, network

As a newbie, it seems a bit abstract for me to imagine how Blockchain works! I'm curious that how my friends and I can join a Blockchain network? When we don't want to stay, can we silently leave and how can we do that?

Well, they may be stupid questions but as a beginner, I really want to understand them as clearly as possible.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You mean joining and leaving the Bitcoin P2P network? Just open & close your node/wallet software...

Comment: @PieterWuille but where and how can I get a node, then any setups necessary? With the wallet, I just need to create a digital one, right?

Comment: Nodes/wallets are just software you can run: https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet. They're all "digital", but if you're referring to websites that offer holding coins for you, those aren't generally to be in the same category (they're more akin to banks, which you have to trust). For those, it's really them that are connected to the Bitcoin network, not you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I understood the concept and it's really a good start for me to go on

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to send an email, so you type your email adress, your password and log in to your mail box, you type the mail receiver adress, and then send the e-mail

In case of Bitcoin, you want to send `0.001 BTC`, so you log in to your wallet (A full node or an application in your phone or your desktop) you type the `BTC adress`, you type the amount, and then send the coins.

When you log in to your wallet, it's like you are connected to the blockchain via a node, when you sign out from your wallet you are no longer connected to the blockchain

Comment: There is really no "connection" to the blockchain. It's a data structure that some nodes have a local copy of. Logging into your wallet may or may not mean you're connected to the network directly - hosted wallets don't give you any connection at all for example, generally.

Comment: @PieterWuille Yes, that's right, just wanted to generally explain how it's for a beginner, thank you for the clarifcation